# new to JQuery, dont know how to use local variables (with greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying out to change a click event from a button with Greasemonkey,
while trying so i came across multiple problems and looked up some things online, but couldn't find any solution i understood or worked for me.

What i was going to try:
i tried to change a site, where it adds 2 elements when a button is pressed (i called the variable "but"),
but i want to remove the second element which it adds, so i overwrote the click event so it does add the 2 elements and right after it executes a function which removes the second element.

so bc iam new i not so sure how to get something from jquery and set it to a local javascript variable.

The problem code:

```
var but = $("#information");
but = but.children()[1];
but = but.find( "div" );
but = but.children[0];
but = but.find("a");
but = but.children[0];

$(but).click(function()
{
    if(condition == 'true')
    {
        $.when(initialize()).then(deletehtml());
    }
});
function deletehtml()
{
    $($( "#content_box" ).children()[1]).remove();
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: First off `but.children()[1]`. [#] breaks an Element out of the jQuery object.  You cannot perform more jQuery methods against it unless you re-wrap it.  Use `eq(#)` instead to keep it in a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar, so first line would be var but = $("#information:eq( 1 )"); then? but how would i get a specific children from a object? <- would it be like this: but = $(but + ":eq( 0 )");  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is your whole problem, but part of your problem is most likely from the use of `[#]`.  That breaks a DOM Element out of the jQuery object and after that you cannot use jQuery methods against it unless you re-wrap `$()` it.  Instead, use `eq(#)` to get the element if you want to keep using jQuery methods against it and to avoid having to re-wrap.

```
var $but = $("#information").children().eq(1);
$but = $but.find( "div" ).first();
$but = $but.find("a").first();

$but.on('click', function() {
    if (condition == 'true') {
        $.when(initialize()).then(deletehtml());
    }
});

function deletehtml() {
    $( "#content_box" ).children().eq(1).remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code @Taplar, expect the click event it works now, but i cant seem to find the solution for the click problem, i tried it with, as u said, " $but.on('click', function() {..." and "$but.click(function(){" which i had. I tried to check if he goes into the click event function with a alert("") but the alert never popped up.. hmm :(

Comment: That would seem to suggest that $but at that point does not have any contained elements.  You should start debugging your $but (heh) step by step to make sure it has what you expect it to have.

Comment: Oh snap, noticed typos.  I left out some $ when i changed the `but` to `$but`.  There, fixed.

Comment: yea i saw the typos too but that wasnt the problem, i dont know if it changed the onclick event to 2 methods bc on firebug it didnt show changes, so i tried to change attribute with: $but.attr("onclick","deletehtml()");   
and that worked :) Thanks again @Taplar!